# What is an imaginary boundary?

Tags: thermodynamics

We know that anything that separates the system with the surroundings is called a boundary.
It is said that a boundary can be either conducting or non-conducting, rigid or nonrigid, and real or imaginary.

What is meant by "imaginary boundary"?

Answer (score 3):

**Boundaries are defined with respect to the system in observation.**

Imagine you're in a room with the door closed. Say, you are measuring the temperature of the room, i.e. the room is your system. In that case, it's easy to understand that the boundaries are real. In this case, the walls, the ceiling, the closed door comprises the boundary of the system.

Now, say somebody opens the door. Understand that this does not change the system; you are still interested in measuring the temperature of the room only. So, we can say that at the place of the closed door, there is an imaginary boundary. By specifying the boundary, you are now able to define your system more clearly.

**This concept of imaginary boundary helps us to clearly define our system.**

Answer (score 0):

"System" refers to the area you're studying in regard to heat changes.
"Boundary" separates the system from the surrounding and, in the case of a system, say a glass of water, there is an *imaginary* boundary on top of the surface of water.

While you may also consider that the glass itself acts as a *real* boundary in the same example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a piece of equipment for which fluid is flowing in and out, you can define your control volume as the entire piece of equipment. This control volume has mostly rigid boundaries, but it also has boundaries through which fluid enters and exits.  The latter are called imaginary boundaries.